# Delete+insert into, without losing parent key references

Tags: mysql

given an user_services table:

```
user_services
user_id  service_id
1           101
1           102
2           102
2           103
2           104
```

and the `services`

```
services:
101    email
102    sport
103    notify
104    gaming
```

sadly services was changed, news were added, or updated, so it looks like this:

```
101    email2
102    sport and fun
103    notify3
104    gaming and funning
105    newService
```

let me not compare one by one and use a UPDATE ... normally, I would just delete and fill it:

```
DELETE FROM services
INSERT INTO
INSERT INTO...
```

but this way `user_services` will be perished! Then how? Cant I just say to MySQL "hey, its ok that Im deleting but will add parent record instead right away, so dont delete connected records!"

Comment: You can use `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` but don't forget to reactive it again after.

Comment: And if you forget, you might end up like this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36727300