# Order of creating and fillig tables

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am doing a program which should recover the database after the drop, but only a part - only tables which user want, don't care about others. I have two arraylists.

1. All tables which I need to generate - tables witch user want, and others witch are related to this tables (all graph)
2. All relations between this tables
   Question is the order of creating and filling tables to maintain data consistency.

Now, my algorithm is:

1. Generate 'free' tables which don't have any relations (if any)
2. Generate this tables with PrimaryKey only (if any)
3. Try to generate tables with ForeignKey as well.

How to check if I can generate data in a table with ForeignKeys? I need to know the order of generating tables with ForeignKeys. How to do it effectively? I am writing in Java.

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy solutions for that:

- Create your tables without foreign keys in any order you want, then add the foreign keys with an `alter table`-statement afterwards.
- Loop through your table list in any order and create all tables that you can create right now because their reference tables already exist (you have to mark them in your list as created, and you have your second list to check the required relations). Repeat that loop until you created all tables (or until you didn't create any table in a run, than you are missing a required table in your list). You can use this to simulate it too: if you run this loop (without creating your tables, just marking it in your list), you can check if your user has selected all required tables (or mark all required tables for your user according to his selection).

If you want to insert data too:

- add the data before you alter the tables with the first method
- add the data when you create the table
- add the data in the same order as in the second method
- use `set @@foreign_key_checks = 0; <insert all your data in any order>; set @@foreign_key_checks = 1;`. This will allow you to insert the data in any order even if the reference data does not yet exists. Unfortunately there will not be a final check when you reenable it (e.g. if you missed some data), so use this with care.

Comment: Exactly. Like [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36727300) who allegedly forgot and then foobar'd his data up.